# Qt Custom Designer Plugin - Not Exporting Widgets Properly

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project that generates a plugin for use in QtDesigner. I also use the same widget classes in a separate project so I can generate a library to use on the application side. Basically, what I have done is define all of my classes as such:

```
#include <QtUiPlugin/QDesignerExportWidget>

class QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT QtMaterialWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
};
```

There are different variations as these classes are implemented in those derive from QWidget in any way.

When I build the plugin, this works great and there's no issue from there. However, when building the library, I get tons of errors relating to `C4273: 'QtMaterialWidget::qt_static_metacall': inconsistent dll linkage` I have tried to switch it from `QDESIGNER_WIDGET_EXPORT` to `Q_WIDGETS_EXPORT` with no improvement.

> Do I even have to export these widgets in these ways?
>
> Is there a better way of doing this.

Here are both of those projects:

Library Project & Code:
`https://github.com/NickJohn547745/MaterialWidgetsLibrary`

Plugin Project & Code:
`https://github.com/NickJohn547745/MaterialWidgetsPlugin`

Widgets Code:
`https://github.com/NickJohn547745/MaterialWidgets`